# How to perform a huge loop in PHP + Doctrine?

Tags: php, performance, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to develop a simple "Ranking" script in PHP using Symfony2 (MongoDB+Doctrine).

```
    $users = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Account')
                ->sort('points', 'DESC')
                ->getQuery()
                ->execute();

    foreach($users as $user){
            // Do nothing
    }
```

I get the following problem:

***PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 25 bytes)***

My database have 80.000 users, so $users have all of them.

Well, I know I can modify php config to allow more memory. And I'm going to do it.
But I'm looking for other type of solution (apart of adding extra memory to PHP config).

The think is I've tried to develop it with a "pagination" but it doesn't work either (I get the error at user 272, 3rd iteration) :

```
    $limit = 100;
    $skip = 0;

    $total = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Account')->count()->getQuery()->execute();
    $max = $total/$limit;

    while($skip<=$max){

        $users = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Account')
            ->sort('points', 'DESC')
            ->limit($limit)
            ->skip($skip*$limit) // 0x100, 1x100, 2x100, 3x100
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();

        foreach($users as $user){
               // Do nothing
        }

        $skip++;

    }
```

Do you have some idea how could I do it?

PS: I think I've done what is suggested in this post: [How to handle huge select query with symfony and doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800978/how-to-handle-huge-select-query-with-symfony-and-doctrine)

Comment: It's sort of a horrible thing to do but you could throttle your loop with a `sleep()` every `n` iterations. Works in a pinch.

Comment: There is not a way to do a find and modify in doctrine where setting a $ranking variable different for each user? $dm->createQueryBuilder('Account')
                    // Find the Account
                    ->update()
                    ->multiple(true)

                    // Update found Account
                    ->field('ranking')->set($rank++)

                    // Options
                    ->upsert(false)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->execute();

Answer (score 8):

See the [documentation for the `iterate()`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-large-results-for-data-processing) method. It's designed for exactly this purpose.

> You can use the iterate() method just to iterate over a large result and no UPDATE or DELETE intention. The IterableResult instance returned from $query->iterate() implements the Iterator interface so you can process a large result without memory problems...

Don't forget to `detach` the result as you use it.

Comment: The link is outdated. Here is the current [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-large-results-for-data-processing).

Answer (score 4):

Doctrine keeps all the entities in memory. So for [batch updates](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html) you need to clear the cache.

```
$dm->flush();
$dm->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
```

Comment: Thank you @OIS. This worked out! More info on the link posted by MattGibson http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html

Comment: @blueocean Ill remember to make the link more obvious in the future. :)